# Powershell script to move files

Tags: powershell

Need a PowerShell script to move file from one folder to another folder after every 12hrs.

```
get-childitem -Path "D:\BLOG\Power Shell\Examples\Source File Path" -Recurse |
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-date).Date} |
move-item -destination "D:\BLOG\Power Shell\Examples\Destination File Path"
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What have you tried so far. Did you search for Task Scheduler?

Comment: you may want to look into the `robocopy` command https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is going to run for a long period / indefinitely, I wouldn't do it via PowerShell, I'd do it via Task Scheduler on the machine instead.

1. Run the code once to make sure it works (including permissions).
2. Save this as a ps1 file on the machine.
3. Search for Task Scheduler on the machine, and create a new task.
4. Set it to run daily & every 12 hours (type this value in if not on the drop-down menu). Be sure to select Run When User Logged Off, as well as any other properties you need to set.

You can also have Task Scheduler notify you if it fails, which is a nice touch. If you need help on TS a quick search should do the trick...

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking for task scheduler online?
You would need to run this PowerShell script (.ps1 file) in a 12 hour interval using "Task Scheduler"

- Open Task scheduler under Administrative Tools" > Task Scheduler Library > Create Task
- Add General Info about the task
- Trigger tab and click the New button > daily > repeat every 12 hours
  The rest of the options are pretty self-explanatory. Hope this helps

To do this using PowerShell you can reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/start-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps